# line renderer collision detection in 3D

Tags: unity, collision-detection, physics

I've been using the code down below to simulate a rope physics (based on this: [Create Rope Bridge, String in Unity - Verlet Integration Part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k32g4ujzxP0&t=55s)).

Currently, it uses edge collider 2d to detect collision. I was wondering if there was way to make it work in 3D as well. Any sorta 3d collision would be great just to make the rope not to go through objects in the scene.

Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RopeBridge : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform StartPoint;
    public Transform EndPoint;

    private LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    public List<RopeSegment> ropeSegments = new List<RopeSegment>();
    public Vector3 forceGravity;
    Vector3 ropeStartPoint;
    [Range(.0f, .1f)]
    public float ropeSegLen = 0.25f;
    [Range(1f, 100f)]
    public int segmentLength;
    public float lineWidth = 0.1f;
    Vector3 changeAmount;

    private Vector3 changeDir;
    private Vector3 changeAmoun;
    private Vector3 velocity;
    [Range(.0f, 1f)]
    public float ropeVelocity;

    public List<Vector2> newVerticies = new List<Vector2>();
    private EdgeCollider2D col;

    void Start() {
        col = GetComponent<EdgeCollider2D>();

        this.lineRenderer = this.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        ropeStartPoint = StartPoint.position;
        for (int i = 0; i < segmentLength; i++) {
            this.ropeSegments.Add(new RopeSegment(ropeStartPoint));
            ropeStartPoint.y -= ropeSegLen;
            newVerticies.Add(new Vector2(ropeStartPoint.x, ropeStartPoint.y));
        }
        col.points = newVerticies.ToArray();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() { this.DrawRope(); }

    private void FixedUpdate() { this.Simulate(); }

    private void Simulate() {
        // SIMULATION
        //  forceGravity = new Vector2(0f, -1f);

        for (int i = 1; i < this.segmentLength; i++) {
            RopeSegment firstSegment = this.ropeSegments[i];
            velocity = firstSegment.posNow - firstSegment.posOld;
            firstSegment.posOld = firstSegment.posNow;
            firstSegment.posNow += velocity = new Vector3(
                velocity.x * ropeVelocity, velocity.y * ropeVelocity,
                velocity.z * ropeVelocity);  // velcoty
            firstSegment.posNow += forceGravity * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
            this.ropeSegments[i] = firstSegment;
        }

        // CONSTRAINTS
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            this.ApplyConstraint();
        }
    }

    private void ApplyConstraint() {
        // Constrant to First Point
        RopeSegment firstSegment = this.ropeSegments[0];
        firstSegment.posNow = this.StartPoint.position;
        this.ropeSegments[0] = firstSegment;

        // Constrant to Second Point
        RopeSegment endSegment = this.ropeSegments[this.ropeSegments.Count - 1];
        endSegment.posNow = this.EndPoint.position;
        this.ropeSegments[this.ropeSegments.Count - 1] = endSegment;

        for (int i = 0; i < this.segmentLength - 1; i++) {
            RopeSegment firstSeg = this.ropeSegments[i];
            RopeSegment secondSeg = this.ropeSegments[i + 1];

            float dist = (firstSeg.posNow - secondSeg.posNow).magnitude;
            float error = Mathf.Abs(dist - this.ropeSegLen);
            changeDir = Vector2.zero;

            if (dist > ropeSegLen) {
                changeDir = (firstSeg.posNow - secondSeg.posNow).normalized;
            } else if (dist < ropeSegLen) {
                changeDir = (secondSeg.posNow - firstSeg.posNow).normalized;
            }

            changeAmount = changeDir * error;
            if (i != 0) {
                firstSeg.posNow -= changeAmount * 0.5f;
                this.ropeSegments[i] = firstSeg;
                secondSeg.posNow += changeAmount * 0.5f;
                this.ropeSegments[i + 1] = secondSeg;
            } else {
                secondSeg.posNow += changeAmount;
                this.ropeSegments[i + 1] = secondSeg;
            }

            newVerticies[i] = this.ropeSegments[i].posNow;
            // ADDITION
        }

        col.points = newVerticies.ToArray();
        // ADDITION
    }

    private void DrawRope() {
        float lineWidth = this.lineWidth;
        lineRenderer.startWidth = lineWidth;
        lineRenderer.endWidth = lineWidth;

        Vector3[] ropePositions = new Vector3[this.segmentLength];
        for (int i = 0; i < this.segmentLength; i++) {
            ropePositions[i] = this.ropeSegments[i].posNow;
            newVerticies[i] = this.ropeSegments[i].posNow;
        }

        lineRenderer.positionCount = ropePositions.Length;
        lineRenderer.SetPositions(ropePositions);
        col.points = newVerticies.ToArray();
    }

    public struct RopeSegment {
        public Vector3 posNow;
        public Vector3 posOld;

        public RopeSegment(Vector3 pos) {
            this.posNow = pos;
            this.posOld = pos;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Presumably you considered using a chain of CapsuleColliders?

Comment: I've thought about it but i have no idea how to put capsule colliders at the position of those points that are stimulating the rope

Comment: Using the methods one would normally use to move physics objects, like `Rigidbody.MovePosition`, `AddForce`, or setting an appropriate `velocity` directly?